# Flat Assembler, как вывести значение регистра на консоль

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Нужно вывести значение регистра cl на консоль. Собственно сама задача заключается в том, чтобы подсчитать сумму элементов, расположенных до максимального значения, но с этим вроде проблем не возникло. FASM.

```
org 100h

Start:

        mov al, byte[Array]
        mov bx, 1
Back:
        cmp byte[Array+bx], al
        jg Max
Back2:
        inc bx
        cmp bx, 10
        jne Back

        mov bx, 0
Back3:
        cmp byte[Array+bx], al
        jl Sum
Back4:
        inc bx
        cmp byte[Array+bx], al
        jne Back3

        mov ah, 08
        int 21h
        ret
;----------------------------------------------    
Array db 2,4,1,1,8,2,3,4,7,2


Max:
        mov al, byte[Array+bx]
        jmp Back2

Sum:
        add cl, byte[Array+bx]
        jmp Back4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Специальной функции прерывания для вывода значения регистра в числовом виде под DOS нет. Нужно писать нужные процедуры вручную.

Пример процедуры перевода 2-байтового беззнакового целого числа в строку в десятичной системе (скопировано с [fasmworld.ru - **Учебный курс. Часть 22. Вывод чисел на консоль**](https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/022-vyvod-chisel-na-konsol/)):

```
;Процедура преобразования слова в строку в десятичном виде (без знака)
; AX - слово
; DI - буфер для строки (5 символов). Значение регистра не сохраняется.
word_to_udec_str:
    push ax
    push cx
    push dx
    push bx
    xor cx,cx               ;Обнуление CX
    mov bx,10               ;В BX делитель (10 для десятичной системы)
 
wtuds_lp1:                  ;Цикл получения остатков от деления
    xor dx,dx               ;Обнуление старшей части двойного слова
    div bx                  ;Деление AX=(DX:AX)/BX, остаток в DX
    add dl,'0'              ;Преобразование остатка в код символа
    push dx                 ;Сохранение в стеке
    inc cx                  ;Увеличение счетчика символов
    test ax,ax              ;Проверка AX
    jnz wtuds_lp1           ;Переход к началу цикла, если частное не 0.
 
wtuds_lp2:                  ;Цикл извлечения символов из стека
    pop dx                  ;Восстановление символа из стека
    mov [di],dl             ;Сохранение символа в буфере
    inc di                  ;Инкремент адреса буфера
    loop wtuds_lp2          ;Команда цикла
 
    pop bx
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop ax
    ret
```

Ну и "надстройка" над этой функцией для перевода байтового числа:

```
;Процедура преобразования байта в строку в десятичном виде (без знака)
; AL - байт.
; DI - буфер для строки (3 символа). Значение регистра не сохраняется.
byte_to_udec_str:
    push ax
    xor ah,ah               ;Преобразование байта в слово (без знака)
    call word_to_udec_str   ;Вызов процедуры для слова без знака
    pop ax
    ret
```

Дальше уже полученную строку выводите на экран.